# How to enter Text in Dev element

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate gist creation in git hub but I am facing an issue while entering data/text in gist content-box( attached image).
I tried using Javascript executer but it did not work

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 js.executeScript("document.evaluate("//*[@id='gists']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/pre", document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML;=" + "s");
```

Please suggest a way to enter text using Selenium.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOTFx.jpg)

URL : https://gist.github.com/

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: Updated post with URL

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath

```
//div[@class='CodeMirror-sizer']
```

So your code can be like this:

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='CodeMirror-sizer']"));
 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='your text comes here';", element);
```

You can use css selector or any other method as well here.
With css selector it will be:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".CodeMirror-sizer"));
```